# How can I have optional services in the Symfony framework?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to be able to get the current logged in user's credentials (email, password, etc) from the container. So, this is what I did:

```
security.token:
    class: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface
    factory: ["@security.token_storage", "getToken"]
    private: true
security.current_user_credentials:
    class: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface 
    factory: ["@security.token", "getUser"]
security.current_user:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    factory: ["@security.current_user_credentials", "getUser"]
```

When I do this and I'm logged in, it works fine. However, when I'm logged out, I get this in `dev.log`:

```
[2015-06-22 12:28:11] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Call to a member function getUser() on string {"type":1,"file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3107,"level":-1,"stack":[{"function":"getSecurity_CurrentUserService","type":"->","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2140,"args":[]},{"function":"get","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":674,"args":[]},{"function":"getCommandHistoryCreatorService","type":"->","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2140,"args":[]},{"function":"get","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1929,"args":[]},{"function":"lazyLoad","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1894,"args":[]},{"function":"getListeners","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":99,"args":[]},{"function":"getListeners","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":158,"args":[]},{"function":"getNotCalledListeners","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/EventDataCollector.php","line":48,"args":[]},{"function":"lateCollect","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DataCollector\\EventDataCollector","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php","line":115,"args":[]},{"function":"saveProfile","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Profiler\\Profiler","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ProfilerListener.php","line":146,"args":[]},{"function":"onKernelTerminate","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ProfilerListener","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"args":[]},{"function":"call_user_func:{/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:61}","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"args":[]},{"function":"__invoke","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1824,"args":[]},{"function":"call_user_func:{/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php:1824}","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1824,"args":[]},{"function":"doDispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1757,"args":[]},{"function":"dispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1918,"args":[]},{"function":"dispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":124,"args":[]},{"function":"dispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3067,"args":[]},{"function":"terminate","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2409,"args":[]},{"function":"terminate","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/web/app_dev.php","line":20,"args":[]},{"function":"{main}","file":"/var/www/html/phoenix/web/app_dev.php","line":0,"args":[]}]} []
```

Is it possible to make the `security.current_user_credentials` and `security.current_user` optional? Is this error caused by these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I ran into a similar issue and if you try to access a route that does not exist you might see the same error. I was working on a task where I needed to get hold of logged in user in my service and this is how I achieved it

My `services.yml`

```
services:
    student_application_subscriber:
        class: namespace\YourBundle\EventListener\StudentApplicationSubscriber
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - @security.token_storage
            - @security.authorization_checker
            - @twig
```

This is my service class `StudentApplicationSubscriber`

```
namespace yournamespace\YourBundleBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


class StudentApplicationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $em;
    protected $twig;
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $authChecker;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em, $tokenStorage, $authChecker, $twig)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {

        return array(
            'kernel.request' => 'onKernelRequest'
        );

    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {

        if (!$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user)) {
            // there is no user - the user may not be logged in
            return;
        }

        //get details of logged in user
        $get_user_details = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        //make sure to pull information when user is logged in
        if ($this->authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {

            //get user id of logged in user
            $userId = $get_user_details->getId();

        //perform your logic here
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please check out my comments above -- I don't want to pass in the whole security context, only to get the logged in user from it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
At first sight I would suggest would be either having a kernel listener that would check if there is a User and performe the required actions, or check that in your `security.current_user_credentials`.

Comment: I am setting up the dependencies for an event listener. However, I don't want to pass in the whole security context when all my service needs is the current user. Also, I don't want to pass in the `security.current_user_credentials` when I want to only use it to access `security.current_user`. However, when the user is anonymous, the object in `security.current_user_credentials` is something other than my own `Credentials` entity, which leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if you just pass to your service and add below logic inside that function, then it work for both annon and authenticated users:

```
function dummyFunction($securityContext)) {
$email = $username = '';
if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
   $email = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getEmail();
   $username = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
}
 ..........................
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass in the whole security context, only to get the current logged in user from it.